# can another person run my android app when I use application restriction or API restriction to the API key in google maps?

Tags: flutter, api, google-maps, api-key

I'm very beginner to flutter apis. I need to know when I use google map's api key with application restriction and api restriction, can other developer run my application ?

Comment: Yes they can. The application restriction is about not using the same API key for different application. The API restriction is about the services the key has access. eg places, maps, gecoding etc.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed using api key with application restriction and api restriction can protect your app as long as you avoid the following approaches:

- **Hardcoding or stroring the API keys directly in the App source code.** The api keys can be read after decompiling the app.
- **Hardcoding or stroring the API keys indirectly in the App.** Even providing the keys via environment variables can not shield them from client
  access as the previous point.
- **Sending the API keys to the App from a controlled service.** Man-in-the-middle attacks can lead the exposing your api keys.

Hope this can give you some idea about the topic.